# Is there any way to optimize my code more to make the formik input faster?

Tags: next.js, formik, yup, mantine

I am developing a diagnostic management website for my client . In one of page there is 10 input field . Every field is working well enough but I have faced an issue with the following **phone** field . I already type number but it is shown to the ui after some time which is not a good user experience. I have made this with formik , yup and next js .

Here is the code :

```
 <SearchableSelect<PatientType>
                    searchField="phoneSearch"
                    name="phone"
                    options={async function loadPatients(phone: string) {
                      if (phone && phone.length > 10) {
                        const { success, data } = await getPatientDataAction(
                          phone
                        );
                        if (success) {
                          return data as PatientType[];
                        } else {
                          console.error(data);
                        }
                      }
                      return [];
                    }}
                    onOptionSubmit={setSelectedPatient}
                    emptyComponent={
                      <Group
                        bg="#F1F3F5"
                        p={6}
                        justify="center"
                        className="cursor"
                      ></Group>
                    }
                    filterSelector={phoneSelector}
                    selector={phoneSelector}
                    renderOption={(item) => (
                      <div className="d-flex gap-3 align-items-center">
                        <Text className="d-block" fw={600} size="md">
                          {item?.name}
                        </Text>
                      </div>
                    )}
                    disabled={
                      individualBill &&
                      authState?.user?.role === "receptionist" &&
                      !diagnosticState?.isEditPatient
                    }
                    label="Enter Phone Number"
                    withAsterisk={true}
                    placeholder="Enter Phone Number"
                  />
```

And here is the SearchAbleSelect component which has been made with mantine and formik :

```
import {
  Combobox,
  TextInput,
  Loader,
  TextInputProps,
  useCombobox,
  CloseButton,
} from "@mantine/core";
import { useField } from "formik";
import { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";

export type SearchableSelectProps<T = string> = TextInputProps & {
  name: string;
  searchField: string;
  options: T[] | ((search: string) => Promise<T[]>);
  onOptionSubmit?: (value: T) => void;
  emptyComponent?: React.JSX.Element;
} & (T extends string
    ? {
        selector?: (value: T) => string;
        renderOption?: (value: T) => React.ReactNode;
        filterSelector?: (value: T) => string;
      }
    : {
        selector: (value: T) => string;
        renderOption: (value: T) => React.ReactNode;
        filterSelector: (value: T) => string;
      });

export function SearchableSelect<T>({
  name,
  searchField,
  options,
  onOptionSubmit,
  emptyComponent,
  selector,
  filterSelector,
  renderOption,
  size = "md",
  radius = "md",
  variant = "filled",
  ...inputProps
}: SearchableSelectProps<T>) {
  // const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const isOptionsDynamic = typeof options === "function";
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState<T[]>(isOptionsDynamic ? [] : options);
  const combobox = useCombobox({
    onDropdownClose: () => combobox.resetSelectedOption(),
    onDropdownOpen: () => {
      // console.log(options);
      if (isOptionsDynamic) {
        setLoading(true);
        options(search).then((response) => {
          setData(response);
          setLoading(false);
          combobox.resetSelectedOption();
        });
      }
    },
  });
  const withDefaults = {
    size,
    variant,
    radius,
  };
  const [{ value, ...field }, meta, { setValue }] = useField(name);
  const [{ value: search, ...field1 }, meta1, { setValue: setSearch }] =
    useField(searchField);

  const filteredOptions = data.filter((item) => {
    const v = filterSelector ? filterSelector(item) : (item as string);
    // console.log(v);
    return (
      v === search || v.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase().trim())
    );
  });
  console.log(value, name);

  return (
    <Combobox
      store={combobox}
      withinPortal={false}
      onOptionSubmit={(val) => {
        const item = JSON.parse(val) as T;
        const value = selector ? selector(item) : (item as string);
        const searchValue = filterSelector
          ? filterSelector(item)
          : (item as string);
        setValue(value);
        setSearch(searchValue);
        combobox.closeDropdown();
        onOptionSubmit?.(item);
        console.log("object,", searchValue, value, item);
      }}
    >
      <Combobox.Target>
        <TextInput
          rightSection={
            loading ? (
              <Loader size={18} />
            ) : value !== null ? (
              <CloseButton
                size="sm"
                onClick={() => {
                  setValue({});
                  setSearch("");
                }}
                aria-label="Clear value"
              />
            ) : (
              <Combobox.Chevron />
            )
          }
          value={search}
          onChange={(event) => {
            const search = event.currentTarget.value;

            combobox.openDropdown();
            combobox.updateSelectedOptionIndex();
            setSearch(search);
            if (name !== "pCId") setValue(search);
            if (isOptionsDynamic) {
              setLoading(true);
              options(search).then((response) => {
                setData(response);
                setLoading(false);
                combobox.resetSelectedOption();
              });
            }
          }}
          onClick={() => combobox.openDropdown()}
          onFocus={() => combobox.openDropdown()}
          onBlur={(event) => {
            combobox.closeDropdown();
            console.log(search, "this is search");
            setSearch(search || "");
            field.onBlur(event);
          }}
          placeholder="Search value"
          rightSectionPointerEvents="none"
          error={meta.touched && meta.error}
          {...withDefaults}
          {...inputProps}
        />
      </Combobox.Target>

      <Combobox.Dropdown>
        <Combobox.Options>
          {filteredOptions.length > 0 ? (
            filteredOptions.map((item) => {
              //    console.log(item);
              const value = JSON.stringify(item);
              return (
                <Combobox.Option value={value} key={value}>
                  {renderOption ? renderOption(item) : (item as string)}
                </Combobox.Option>
              );
            })
          ) : loading ? (
            <Combobox.Empty>Loading....</Combobox.Empty>
          ) : (
            <Combobox.Empty>{emptyComponent ?? "Nothing found"}</Combobox.Empty>
          )}
        </Combobox.Options>
      </Combobox.Dropdown>
    </Combobox>
  );
}
```

Please give me idea such that I can make this input field more faster .